# Adding items from a list to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently doing the second exercise found here.
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter5 ("List to Dictionary Function for Fantasy Game Inventory")

The task is to add the items from a list to a dictionary.

For some weird reason, my for loop is not looping through the whole list. Can you help me to understand why?

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        if i in inventory:
            inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
        else:
            inventory[i] = 1
        return inventory

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
print(inv)
```

When I run this code, the result is "{'rope': 1, 'gold coin': 43}"
So the value of the gold coin key is increased by 1 (not by 3 which it is supposed to), and 'dagger' and 'ruby' are ignored.

I have found a working solution elsewhere, but I really want to understand why this code doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return inventory` is within your `for` loop!!! it returns immediately

Answer (score 2):

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        if i in inventory:
            inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
        else:
            inventory[i] = 1
    return inventory
```

(`return` after `for`, not after `if`.)

Comment: I wonder why this got a down vote; it's the correct answer!

Comment: You've provided code and shown what you've changed, but haven't explained why. (note: I'm not a downvoter)

Comment: furthermore this is just a typo. OP should know about indenting the code properly.

Comment: Wow this is amazing how fast you guys are. And I am happy that I was sooo close after all (spent an hour trying to fix this :P). Thanks!

Comment: @ArthurTacca> because the proper response to such a question is to flag it as "off topic because it is a simple typo error", perhaps with a hint in the comments. Answering is dubious at best, answering with no explanation just looks like shameless reputation grinding.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume that the definition of a "typo" would be "I know what I did wrong but I just did not see it?".

In this case, I did not know what the problem was. So I don't call it a typo. Kirill's response helped me. That's what matters, doesn't it?

Comment: @spectras "no explanation" is reasonable, but the first half of your reason reads like a thinly-veiled attack on beginners using StackOverflow. I remember when it wasn't like that :-(

Comment: @ArthurTacca> I don't see it. The point of SO is not just to answer one user, but to keep good answers around for good questions, and close the others. Questions involving typos or misplaced commands lie in the "others" category because they are useless to other people. Pointing out the mistake in a comment as Jean-François Fabre did is enough. Copy-pasting the code without any further explanation is a low quality answer to me. Now, you can disagree, you're as free to upvote it as I am to downvote it. You're eve *more* free actually, as I pay for the downvote with my own rep.

Comment: @spectras: same for me, but downvoting a "working" answer (even low-qual as it is) creates upvoting reactions from others who don't agree... I'll keep that answer as a target for further duplicates that will occur...

Comment: @spectras To give you an additional perspective: I searched on Google for this specific exercise but found very little. Nothing on SO that included the exercise title "List to Dictionary Function for Fantasy Game Inventory". So with my question, even though it was related to a "typo", people can actually find a working solution on SO when searching for the task title. So I'd argue this one is not useless to others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a simple indentation typo. Now if we were trying to write some more efficient/pythonic code, we could just use `collections.Counter` which is a specialized dictionary type which counts items. Your code can be shortened and optimized:

```
from collections import Counter

inv = Counter({'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1})

inv.update(['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby'])

print(inv)
```

result:

```
Counter({'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1})
```

Comment: thanks for downvoting an answer that tries to improve python coding.

Comment: and thanks for the corrective upvote :)